# Cannot pass $pdo as parameter in function triggered with onclick()

Tags: php, ajax, pdo, onclick

I have a html button that has an onclick method, which triggers some things to happen with ajax. The variables passed through the function, however, are in php. Here is the code:

**Html/PHP**

```
#Do not mind the first forward slash#
/<button type="submit" 
    name="follow_button" 
    onclick= <?php 
        echo "'follow_alert(" . $pdo . ", " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ", " . $value['user_id'].");'" 
        ?> 
>Follow
</button>
```

Both variables $_SESSION['user_id'] and $value['user_id'] are passing fine. I have tried the code and it works without $pdo, but the problem is I need $pdo to be called to access it in my php function which fetches data from my mysql table.

Here is the JS.

**JS**

```
function follow_alert(pdo, user_id, following_id) {
    var ajax = ajaxRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
            alert(ajax.responseText);
        };
    };
    ajax.open('GET', 'function.php?pdo='+pdo+'&user_id='+user_id+'&following_id='+following_id, true);
    ajax.send(null);
};
```

My problem is : I keep getting a **"Catchable fatal error : Object of class PDO could not be converted to string"** error. when I pass $pdo as parameters in all my other functions, they work fine. The problem just seems to be that I'm passing it through a string to be run onclick(); At least that is what I think it is.

Any thoughts? I've been wracking my mind over this all morning!

Comment: You need to remember that JS runs on the client and PHP runs on the server.

Comment: @nickb hey can you expound on the ramifications of that statement? I'm very new to PHP and JS, and even newer to programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t pass a resource, like a PDO instance, to a JavaScript function. It doesn’t exist by the time the HTML is rendered. You’ll need to create the PDO instance in the PHP script your JavaScript function calls.

Comment: Let me try that out right now! I will get back to you, thanks a lot!

Comment: you are such a blessing to have on this site. Thank you SO FREAKING MUCH. Keep doing what you do man. will accept the answer in 7 minutes!